# Type-conversion aware numeric literals

Tags: c++

As far I know, different numeric literals have different types in C and C++. For example:

- `0` is of type `int`.
- `0u` is of type `unsigned int`.
- `0.0` is of type `double`.
- `0.0f` is of type `float`.
  etc.

So if you initialize a variable with a literal value, the type of that literal must be the same of the variable, else a type conversion is done to perform the assigment:

```
int i = 0.0;
```

That seems like a stupid conversion, and because the value of a literal is known at compile-time, the compiler could easily avoid that conversion and just assign the value in the correct format (signed integer instead of floating-point, in the example).

My question is very simple: **Is guaranteed that any decent (Or at least any modern compiler, I'm working with GCC 4.8.2) elides that conversion?**

I'm writting a couple of generic classes for algebra, and I'm worried about initialization with literals, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct vector_2d
{
    T x , y;

    vector_2d( T xx , T yy ) : x( xx ) , y( yy ) {}

    //Initializations like this:
    vector_2d() : vector_2d( 0 , 0 ) {}
};
```

Because I don't know which type is `T`, I cannot use `0.0f` when the type is `float` and so on. Of course I'm not going to write template specializations to catch the different type of parameters :P

Comment: It is not "guaranteed", but certainly any modern optimizing compiler does as many conversion elisions as it can without violating the Standard.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "guaranteed" - the standard doesn't require it, so I guess the literal answer is "no"!

Comment: But would the cost of such conversions (if done) be huge?

Comment: @UchiaItachi: inside an inner loop (which I could believe a class like `vector_2d` may well be), that could be significant.

Comment: In C++11 you can use a [constexpr function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) template to ensure that the conversion is performed at compile-time.

Comment: The purple dragon book has this optimization in its first optimization example, so you can rest assured :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use value-initialization to get a "zero" value of the appropriate type.

```
vector_2d() : vector_2d( T() , T() ) {}
```

or

```
vector_2d() : x(), y() {}
```

This only works for zero, of course.  For other values you would want a `constexpr` function template as Nikolay commented.

```
template<typename TResult, typename TFrom>
constexpr TResult compiletime_conversion(const TFrom val)
{
    TResult result = val;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The member initialization is just an example case, and also I'm not talking of zero initialization only. But in case of zeros, this is better of course.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that `constexpr` function? I got and understand the idea, but I prefer to see an example first (And its better for others who look at this thread later). Thanks.

Comment: @Manu343726: There's an example.

Comment: that looks like `static_cast<>` Just use `static_cast` :) Thanks

Comment: Except that static_cast is not an explicit request to the compiler to do it at compile time. And that this will only trigger implicit conversions.

Comment: is not `static_cast<>` performed at compile-time always?

Comment: @Manu: No it isn't.  The conversion sequence is determined at compile time, but the actual conversion of the value may take place at runtime (after all, the value may not be known until runtime).  The same is true of `constexpr` functions, but those are specifically meant for compile-time calculation, so it's a strong request to the compiler to do so.